# Modificar CSS de los elementos de un iframe mediante JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

Me gustaría saber como puedo modificar el CSS de etiquetas y clases que hay dentro de un `iframe`, he encontrado soluciones en JavaScript, pero no soy capaz de hacerlas funcionar.

Concretamente quiero maquetar los enlaces de abajo del pop up que sale al picar en las banderas, el CSS lo tengo:

```
.ql-snow .ql-editor a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: brown;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid brown;
    display: inherit;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

ademas quiero poner una imagen de fondo

```
.si-content-wrapper {
    background-image: url(http://casonacalderon.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/69896840-papyrus-wallpapers.jpeg);
}
```

Pero como os digo, no soy capaz de llegar a esas etiquetas para modificarlas, sé que mediante CSS no puedo, pero he visto posibles soluciones en JavaScript.

Comment: no puedes modificar un objeto (cualquiera) si estás accesandolo por medio de HTTP.

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir cómo lo has intentado con JavaScript? Un [mcve] sería ideal para reproducir el problema y poder ayudarte.

Comment: Hola tengo una duda: ¿Por qué usar Popups? Es necesario cargarlo vía iframe? Muchas veces los Iframes no son la opción más certera, todo depende de cual sea el objetivo. 

Tampoco conozco el código y la descripción de lo que debe suceder no es muy explícita, sin embargo, por lo que entiendo podrías generar el código dinámicamente mediante javascript o php y no usar iframes.

Comment: Hola de nuevo, quiero insertar este mapa:

https://snazzymaps.com/build-a-map/preview/35836

Los hago mediante ente iframe

<iframe src="https://snazzymaps.com/embed/35836" width="100%" height="700px" style="border:none;"></iframe>

He visto como hacerlo en esta web, pero no tengo claro que funcione:
http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/refs/iframe.php

Answer (score 2):

Termino de tener el mismo problema, para modificar el css de un iframe desde JavaScript, se tiene que hacer al interno de la misma pagina, es decir no es cross-domain, si pones el codigo en una hoja .js que despues importas a la pagina, no funciona.

yo pude aplicarle el estilo en este modo:

```html
<head>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256- 2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<iframe id="iframe1"></iframe>

<script>
  var cssLink = document.createElement("link");
  cssLink.href= "iframe.css";
  cssLink.rel = "stylesheet";
  cssLink.type="text/css";
  $("#iframe1").contents().find("head").append(cssLink);
</script>
```

veo que la pregunta ya tiene un buen tiempo, espero que pueda servir igualmente para ayudar a alguien

[Respuesta Original - en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe)